# How do I disable background data in Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: sync, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

The option for "Background data" used to be under Accounts & sync in Android 2.3.  But on my Galaxy Nexus, the option is missing.  Therefore some applications are still using background data... How can I disable "Background data" in ICS?

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 9):

Settings / Data Usage / Menu button / Restrict Background Data

[image: Restrict Background Data]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: I think this is it... weird, it requires you to set a mobile data limit :/

Comment: Bryan Denny's solution works, but beware that in ICS, it applies only to cellular data connections and not WiFi - even on a phone. Source: [xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1514053)